# Problema al borrar un registro de la base de datos en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Me gustaría borrar de la base de datos el elemento que selecciono con el menú contextual.
El problema es que al poner la condición de borrado, la aplicación no me funciona.

Esta sería mi función borrar.

```
private void borrarLibro(int posicion) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

    String titulo = listaLibros.get(posicion).getTitulo();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), titulo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    if(numRegistros() == 1) {
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_LIBROS);
    }
    else {

        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_LIBROS +
                " WHERE " + Utilidades.CAMPO_TITULO + " = '" + titulo + "'");
    }

    db.close();
}
```

Lo que no entiendo es que si hago un delete from libros la aplicación sí que me funciona pero al intentar meterle la condición no me funciona.

```
@Override
public void onDatosBorrar(int posicion) {
    listaLibros.remove(posicion);
    borrarLibro(posicion);
    numRegistros();
    adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Clase Utlidades:

package com.example.biblioteca.utilidades;

```
public class Utilidades {

    //Constantes campos tabla libros
    public static final String TABLA_LIBROS = "libros";
    public static final String CAMPO_ID = "_id";
    public static final String CAMPO_CATEGORIA = "categoria";
    public static final String CAMPO_TITULO = "titulo";
    public static final String CAMPO_AUTOR = "autor";
    public static final String CAMPO_IDIOMA = "idioma";
    public static final String CAMPO_FECHA_LECTURA_INI = "fecha_lectura_ini";
    public static final String CAMPO_FECHA_LECTURA_FIN = "fecha_lectura_FIN";
    public static final String CAMPO_PRESTADO_A = "prestado_a";
    public static final String CAMPO_VALORACION = "valoracion";
    public static final String CAMPO_FORMATO = "formato";
    public static final String CAMPO_NOTAS = "notas";

    public static final String CREAR_TABLA_LIBRO = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLA_LIBROS + "(" + CAMPO_ID +" integer primary key autoincrement, \n" +
            "\t "+CAMPO_CATEGORIA+ " text not null, "+ CAMPO_TITULO + " text not null, " + CAMPO_AUTOR + " text not null, " + CAMPO_IDIOMA + " text, \n" +
            "\t "+CAMPO_FECHA_LECTURA_INI+ " long, "+ CAMPO_FECHA_LECTURA_FIN + " long, " +CAMPO_PRESTADO_A+ " text, " +CAMPO_VALORACION+ " float,  \n" +
            CAMPO_FORMATO +  " text, "+ CAMPO_NOTAS + " text);\n";
}
```

Comment: Graciás de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? ¿Verificaste que cada variable tiene el valor correcto y que las condiciones se cumplen? Pon puntos de depuración en tu IDE y ve revisando el estado de cada objeto/variable implicado.

Comment: lo que no funciona es la línea: String titulo = listaLibros.get(posicion).getTitulo();

Answer (score 1):

Vale ya he descubierto el problema.
La cosa es que primero eliminaba el objeto de la lista y luego de la base de datos. Claro, al haber eliminado primero el objeto de la lista accedía a otra posición de la lista y por lo tanto a otro objeto. La solución es primero eliminar el objeto de la base de datos y después de la lista.

```
@Override
    public void onDatosBorrar(int posicion) {
        //pos = posicion;
        borrarLibro(posicion);
        listaLibros.remove(posicion);
        numRegistros();
        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```